# Separation of variables using polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I understand that a circle in cartesian coordinates is not a rectangular domain and using polar coordinates gives us our required domain to solve a PDE by separation of variables. However I do not understand very well on how to change certain boundary and initial conditions from the cartesian problem to the polar form. For example :

$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, $x^2 + y^2<1$, $x>0$

$u(0,y)=1$

$u(x,y)=1+x^2$, for $x^2 +y^2=1, x>0$

I understand that our equation that we need to solve is the laplacian in polar coordinates and that $0<r<1$ and $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$ but what happens to the initial and boundary conditions?

Comment: If $v(r,t)$ is $u(x,y)$ in polar coordinates, then $u(0,y) = 1$ means $v(r,\pm\pi/2) = 1$ for $r\in [0,1]$ and $u(x,y) = 1+x^2$ for $x^2+y^2=1$ means $v(1,t) = 1+\cos^2 t$ for $t\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. By the way, these are only boundary values. There are no "initial values".

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.How would you change the boundary values so that they're homogeneous. I am also struggling to understand on how to solve a pde with inhomogeneous boundary values?

Comment: You can certainly start by writing the boundary conditions as functions of $r$ and $\theta$. Are you familiar with the method of projections to write a series expansion that fits the boundaries, perhaps from Cartesian coordinates?